# How to join tables those tables using query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

How can I join those two tables?:

Table 1:

| City1 | OptA | m |

| City1 | OptA | f |

| City1 | OptB | m |

| City1 | OptB | f |

| City2 | OptA | m |

| City2 | OptA | f |

| City2 | OptB | m |

| City2 | OptB | f |

Table 2:

| City1 | m | |value |

| City1 | f | value |

| City2 | m | value |

| City2 | f | value |

Result:

| City1 | OptA | m | value |

| City1 | OptA | f | value |

| City1 | OptB | m | value |

| City1 | OptB | f | value |

| City2 | OptA | m | value |

| City2 | OptA | f | value |

| City2 | OptB | m | value |

| City2 | OptB | f | value |

I just cannot get it working right... I have relationships based in Id of city...

Thank you.

Comment: How about posting the query you have so far. Basically you can just use the query wizard to join on ID and select the fields you want to display. Assuming there is no 'grouping' or 'totals' desired, that is the easiest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a simple join on the city column like

```
select t1.*, t2.value
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.city = t2.city;
```

Comment: This was my first approach but it doubles my data in Table 1... It inserts both "m value" and "f value" for every "City". it doesn't  consider "f" and "m". How can I fix it?